# How to Fix CodeIgniter Base_url and css link

Tags: codeigniter

I'm New to Code-igniter and I'm trying to create login form with session.I'm stuck at a point where username and password field is empty than its not showing CSS.

i research a bit more about it and found that when i first open my project_login form at that moment css link looks likes this localhost/ci_project/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/mystyle.css

after click on login button when username and password are empty at that moment css link look like this (Auth is my controller where i written login function)
localhost/ci_project/Auth/assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/mystyle.css

`login.php`

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
  <title>AdminLTE 2 | Log in</title>
  <!-- Tell the browser to be responsive to screen width -->
  <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, user-scalable=no" name="viewport">
  <!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url()?>assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!-- Font Awesome -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url()?>assets/bower_components/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
  <!-- Ionicons -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url()?>assets/bower_components/Ionicons/css/ionicons.min.css">
  <!-- Theme style -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url()?>assets/dist/css/AdminLTE.min.css">
  <!-- iCheck -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php base_url()?>assets/plugins/iCheck/square/blue.css">

  <!-- HTML5 Shim and Respond.js IE8 support of HTML5 elements and media queries -->
  <!-- WARNING: Respond.js doesn't work if you view the page via file:// -->
  <!--[if lt IE 9]>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/html5shiv/3.7.3/html5shiv.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://oss.maxcdn.com/respond/1.4.2/respond.min.js"></script>
  <![endif]-->

  <!-- Google Font -->
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Source+Sans+Pro:300,400,600,700,300italic,400italic,600italic">
</head>
<body class="hold-transition login-page">
<div class="login-box">
  <div class="login-logo">
    <a href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>"><b>VEMS</b> ER</a>
  </div>
  <!-- /.login-logo -->
  <div class="login-box-body">
    <h4><p class="login-box-msg">VEMS ENGINEERING MULTI SERVICE</p></h4>
    <form action="<?php echo base_url()?>Auth/login_validation" method="post">
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="username" name="username" class="form-control" placeholder="Email">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('username'); ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="form-group has-feedback">
        <input type="password" name="password" class="form-control" placeholder="Password">
        <span class="text-danger"><?php echo form_error('password'); ?></span>
      </div>
      <div class="row">
        <?php echo $this->session->flashdata("error"); ?>
        <div class="col-xs-8">
          <div class="checkbox icheck">
            <label>
              <input type="checkbox" class="login-check" checked="checked"> Remember Me
            </label>
          </div>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
        <div class="col-xs-4">
          <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block btn-flat">Sign In</button>
        </div>
        <!-- /.col -->
      </div>
    </form>

    <!-- <div class="social-auth-links text-center">
      <p>- OR -</p>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-facebook btn-flat"><i class="fa fa-facebook"></i> Sign in using
        Facebook</a>
      <a href="#" class="btn btn-block btn-social btn-google btn-flat"> Sign in using
        Google+</a>
    </div> -->
    <!-- /.social-auth-links -->

    <a href="#">I forgot my password</a><br>
    <!-- <a href="register.html" class="text-center">Register a new membership</a> -->

  </div>
  <!-- /.login-box-body -->
</div>
<!-- /.login-box -->

<!-- jQuery 3 -->
<script src="<?php base_url()?>assets/bower_components/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!-- Bootstrap 3.3.7 -->
<script src="<?php base_url()?>assets/bower_components/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<!-- iCheck -->
<script src="<?php base_url()?>assets/plugins/iCheck/icheck.min.js"></script>
<script>
  $(function () {
    $('input').iCheck({
      checkboxClass: 'icheckbox_square-blue',
      radioClass: 'iradio_square-blue',
      increaseArea: '20%' /* optional */
    });
  });
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

`Auth.php (Controller)`

```
<?php
defined('BASEPATH') OR exit('No direct script access allowed');

class Auth extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct(){
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->helper('url');
        $this->load->helper('form');
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $this->load->model('Auth_model');   
    }

    public function index(){
        $this->load->view('pages/login');
    }

    public function login_validation(){
        $this->load->library('form_validation');
        $data['title'] = "Login";
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('username', 'Username', 'trim|required|valid_email');
        $this->form_validation->set_rules('password', 'Password', 'required');

        if($this->form_validation->run()){
            //get value from login form by post method
            $username = $this->input->post('username'); //email
            $username = $this->input->post('password'); //password
            //model function
            $this->load->model('Auth_model');
            if($this->Auth_model->can_login($username, $password)){
                $session_data = array(
                    'username' => $username
                );
                $this->session->set_userdata($session_data);
                redirect(base_url(). 'Auth/enter');
            }
            else{
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Invalid Username Or password');
                redirect(base_url(). 'Auth');
            }
        }
        else{       
            $this->load->view('pages/login');
        }
    }

    public function enter(){
        if($this->session->userdata('username') != ''){
            echo "<h2>Welcome".$this->session->userdata('username')."</h2>";
            echo '<a href="'.base_url().'Auth/logout>LOGOUT</a>';
        }
        else{
            redirect(base_url(). 'Auth');
        }
    }

    public function logout(){
        $this->session->session_destroy();
        redirect('pages/login');
    }
}
```

`$config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/ci_project/'
;`

Comment: try the relative path, like this: `href="/assets/bower_components/etc...`

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it worked if you don't mid to explain why is that not working with base_url()

Comment: try to autoload the url helper and remove manual loading. see if it works then